# Getting continuous UDP data in tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, udp

I am new using Tkinter, I have an issue receiving UDP data.
I have an app that has 2 buttons: "start recording" and "stop recording".

I followed some instructions given in here in other people questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764958/python-3-udp-packet-send-receive-in-a-tkinter-gui) but still I couldn't manage to make that work as expected.
My program freezes and I cannot use the other buttons anymore, I know that it comes from the fact that I am not going through the mainloop anymore, but I don't know how to do so.

My app is really simple for now:

```py
from tkinter import *
import socket

UDP_PORT = 40
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"

class Client:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Title")
        root.geometry("550x350")
        root.resizable(0, 0)

        back = Frame(root, bg='black')
        Label(root, text="LABEL", anchor='w', width=20).grid(row=1, column=0)   
        self.start_recording_button = Button(root, text="Start Recording", command=self.start_recording, anchor='w',
                                           width=20)

        self.start_recording_button.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.stop_recording_button = Button(root, text="Stop Recording", command=self.stop_recording, anchor='w',
                                          width=20)
        self.stop_recording_button.grid(row=6, column=0)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.receiving = True

    def stop_receiving(self):
        self.receiving = False

    def initialize_udp(self):
        self.sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


    def start_receiving(self):
        if self.receiving == True:
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print(data)
            self.root.after(1000, self.start_receiving())

    def start_recording(self):
        self.initialize_udp()
        self.start_receiving()

    def stop_recording(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    gui = Client(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `recvfrom()` is a blocking function, so it is better to run it in a child thread.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I'm sharing it if someone needs the solution in the future.
Just create a while loop that updates the GUI, thus the mainloop doesn't freeze.

```py
from tkinter import *
import socket 
from threading import Thread

UDP_PORT = 40
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"

class Client:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        root.title("Title")
        root.geometry("550x350")
        root.resizable(0, 0)

        back = Frame(root, bg='black')
        Label(root, text="LABEL", anchor='w', width=20).grid(row=1, column=0)   
        self.start_recording_button = Button(root, text="Start Recording", command=self.start_recording, anchor='w',
                                           width=20)

        self.start_recording_button.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.stop_recording_button = Button(root, text="Stop Recording", command=self.stop_recording, anchor='w',
                                          width=20)
        self.stop_recording_button.grid(row=6, column=0)

        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.receiving = True

        self.initialize_udp()


    def stop_receiving(self):
        self.receiving = False

    def initialize_udp(self):
        self.sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    def receiving_udp(self):
        while self.receiving == True:
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print(data)
            self.root.update()

    def start_recording(self):
        
        print("start receiving udp data")
        self.receiving = True
        self.receiving_udp()


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.stop_receiving()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    gui = Client(root)
    gui.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You'd be better off putting a call to `after()` inside `receiving_udp` with some small delay rather than using a `while` loop and `root.update()`. This is the idiomatic way to handle this situation in a tkinter app and comes with less overhead. `root.after(100, receiving_udp)` will tell the receiver function to call itself again every 100mS.